# Proof verification: The mappings set between two sets is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I want to prove that the mappings set between two sets is a set. Here's what I did:

> Let $X,Y$ be sets. We've seen that $X\times Y$ is a set as well, so
> from the power set axiom we get that $\mathcal{P}\left(X\times Y\right)$ is a set as well.

> Now we define the formula

$$P\left(z\right):\forall x\ \left(\exists
 y\ \left\langle x,y\right\rangle \in z\right) \\
 \land\left(\forall
 y_{1}\forall y_{2}\ \left\langle x,y_{1}\right\rangle \in
 z\land\left\langle x,y_{2}\right\rangle \in z\rightarrow
 y_{1}=y_{2}\right)$$

> which gives us both a value for each x and uniqueness, therefore the relation will be a function. So from the axiom of separation with  $\mathcal{P}\left(X\times Y\right)$ we are done.

I'm mostly wondering if my use of the axiom of separation is correct - I'm having trouble with the "formula" part. Should I use the axiom of replacement instead?

Comment: This looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks fine, except $\forall x$ should be $\forall x\in X$, and likewise for the other quantifiers.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss Well that's exactly what I was worried about. But if I add X, that means z isn't the only free variable anymore. Is that still acceptable?

Comment: There's an implicit $\forall X\forall Y$ around the whole thing. That is, the claim is that for any sets $X$ and $Y$, there is a set of all mappings from $X$ to $Y$. So no worries.

Comment: @MichaelWeiss thank you kindly